# How to skip testRuntime task in gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In my eclipse, there are many projects that build with gradle. I want to skip the testRuntime task in gradle. Because It's too slow and makes me wait for long time whenever I change some code or give changes the projects. How can I avoid this? I want to apply every relevant projects.

---

**UPDATE**

This is the result of gradle task. Eclipse is executing background job and I check these jobs in the process tab and I can see this message like the followings.

> Gradle Build on xxx project
>
> Executing tasks : xxxx:TestRuntime

I think It takes time because of firewall. I want to skip this process. I guess, It can be done by eclipse or by gradle configuration.

My build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { // for thridparty lib
        url 'http://70.121.244.11:8081/nexus/content/groups/openpms-public'
        credentials {
            username 'openpms'
            password 'openpms0'
        }
     }
     maven { // for thridparty lib
        url 'http://70.121.244.11:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty'
        credentials {
            username 'developer'
            password 'developer0'
        }
     }
    maven { url 'http://70.121.224.52:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/' }
    jcenter{ url 'http://70.121.224.52:8081/nexus/content/repositories/jcenter/' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:$gretty_version"
  }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url 'http://70.121.244.11:8081/nexus/content/groups/openpms-public'
        credentials {
            username "$maven_username"
            password "$maven_password"
        }
     }

    maven { // for thridparty lib
        url 'http://70.121.244.11:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty'
        credentials {
            username 'developer'
            password 'developer0'
        }
     }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8' // compileGroovy, compileTestGroovy

def spring_version = '4.0.6.RELEASE'

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    compile group: 'org.opensymphony.quartz', name: 'quartz', version: '1.6.1'
    compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.0.4'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
}

gretty {
      servletContainer = 'jetty8'
      port = 8080
      contextPath = '/agent.server'
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      tasks
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
<org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.PmdExtension_Decorated@729eaf4b __dyn_obj__=org.gradle.api.internal.AsmBackedClassGenerator$MixInExtensibleDynamicObject@2fc49256 __mapping__=org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper@1263649a __consoleOutput__=false __ignoreFailures__=true __reportsDir__=true __ruleSetConfig__=false __ruleSetFiles__=true __ruleSets__=true __sourceSets__=true __targetJdk__=false __toolVersion__=true project=root project 'redca-agent' ruleSets=[basic] targetJdk=null ruleSetConfig=null ruleSetFiles=file collection consoleOutput=false toolVersion=4.3 sourceSets=[source set 'main'] ignoreFailures=true reportsDir=D:\workspace\redCAGit\redca-agent\build\reports\pmd>
:tasks

------------------------------------------------------------
All tasks runnable from root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Application tasks
-----------------
bootRun - Run the project with support for auto-detecting main class and reloading static resources
installApp - Installs the project as a JVM application along with libs and OS specific scripts.
run - Runs this project as a JVM application

Build tasks
-----------
assemble - Assembles the outputs of this project.
bootRepackage - Repackage existing JAR and WAR archives so that they can be executed from the command line using 'java -jar'
build - Assembles and tests this project.
buildDependents - Assembles and tests this project and all projects that depend on it.
buildNeeded - Assembles and tests this project and all projects it depends on.
classes - Assembles classes 'main'.
clean - Deletes the build directory.
jar - Assembles a jar archive containing the main classes.
testClasses - Assembles classes 'test'.

Build Setup tasks
-----------------
init - Initializes a new Gradle build. [incubating]
wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files. [incubating]

Distribution tasks
------------------
assembleDist - Assembles the main distributions
distTar - Bundles the project as a distribution.
distZip - Bundles the project as a distribution.
installDist - Installs the project as a distribution as-is.

Documentation tasks
-------------------
javadoc - Generates Javadoc API documentation for the main source code.

Help tasks
----------
components - Displays the components produced by root project 'redca-agent'. [incubating]
dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'redca-agent'.
dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project 'redca-agent'.
help - Displays a help message.
model - Displays the configuration model of root project 'redca-agent'. [incubating]
projects - Displays the sub-projects of root project 'redca-agent'.
properties - Displays the properties of root project 'redca-agent'.
tasks - Displays the tasks runnable from root project 'redca-agent' (some of the displayed tasks may belong to subprojects).

Verification tasks
------------------
check - Runs all checks.
test - Runs the unit tests.

Other tasks
-----------
findbugsTest - Run FindBugs analysis for test classes
pmdTest - Run PMD analysis for test classes

Rules
-----
Pattern: clean<TaskName>: Cleans the output files of a task.
Pattern: build<ConfigurationName>: Assembles the artifacts of a configuration.
Pattern: upload<ConfigurationName>: Assembles and uploads the artifacts belonging to a configuration.

To see all tasks and more detail, run gradle tasks --all

To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.354 secs
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Build finished succesfully!
[sts] Time taken: 0 min, 2 sec
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
```

I want to know the way to skip working testRuntime.
Even if it is not task, my concern is not to waste time. 
How can I avoid this?

Comment: testRuntime is not a task. It's a configuration. I thus don't have any idea of what you're actually asking. Describe what you're doing and what is slow, precisely.

Comment: If you have a firewall problem, fix the firewall problem. Gradle needs access to the network to download dependencies from the repositories. But again, TestRuntime is not a standard task, so it must be one of your custom tasks, and we have no idea what it's doing.

Comment: @JBNizet So you mean,  TestRuntime is not standard task, So there is no way to skip?   Can you give hint if I attached my build.gradle file?

Comment: @verystrongjoe could you please run in console `gradle tasks` and share the output? This is the easiest way to know if `testRuntime` is a task.

Comment: @Opal I updated. and JB taught that is not task. But how can I make eclipse not to run that?

Comment: I still don't understand what you don't want to run.

Answer (score 1):

I am a newbie in gradle and I am not goot at English. Please understand.

Anyway, I solved by myself. Eclipse gradle plugin, I am using, is trying to connect the repository on the internet that may be blocked by firewall. So I can't solve this. There are many workplaces including the place where is offline.

I could skip this giving the parameter to Program Arguments like the followings. you can add this property in eclipse preference > Gradle > Arguments.

```
--offline
```